# Key and Message generated on Client, and validated by Server

Tags: public-key, tls

(Sorry in advance for my blurry thinking on this: I'm a programmer, not a cryptography expert.)

I have a Client/Server web application. The Client needs to be able to alter the local state in ways that the program's code allows, but should not be able to "open the hood" to tamper directly with code or data itself, and thereby make "fraudulent" changes.

I was imagining that a solution would be for the Client program's code (with no Server interaction at the time of Event generation) to generate a Key for each audit-able Event. The Key would be directly and solely related to the Event itself, and the Client program's code would generate the Key, but it would be very hard to "spoof" the Key/Event pair by an attempted fraudster.

Then, when the Client went to "save" the Event to Server, the Server would use a Private Key to validate the Event. (And, obviously, if the Key didn't line up with the Event, the Event would be disregarded as invalid -- intentionally or otherwise.)

Thanks for any help. I have the vague sense that what I want is already being done commonly...

Comment: To clarify, you want the client to have the code that generates the key where the code itself doesn't disclose the key?  Is the fraudster impersonating a genuine user, or a genuine user saving events they haven't yet "unlocked" (like a game)?

Comment: The fraudster is a genuine user who is a game "cheater" -- precisely. They're trying to modify their local data to say they found 1,000 Gold when they didn't.

And what I'd be wanting the client-side code to be able to achieve (again, my ignorance is probably showing here) is that the client-side could be 100% offline at the time, find 1,000 Gold, and generate a Key associated with that Gold find that would prove to the Server that the find was "valid".

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this. I suppose a follow up question would be how do you hide the location of the gold in the games code? Or perhaps that is part of your question. Are the client side code/keys to be generated uniquely for each player?

Comment: Hey, no sweat. The Server generates a level, and it knows where the Chest is, the Chest has a unique ID, and the Server knows how much Gold is in the Chest. What I'm trying to prevent is the Player simply scanning the data downloaded into their Browser, figuring out the Chest ID, and transferring the Gold to their inventory. (And I am open to generating as many unique keys as is needed to make this work.) I'm starting to think I simply can't avoid Server trips anytime Inventory changes hands.

Comment: Yeah but I meant the client side code must also know where the chest is, in order to play the game.  And if the player can read the code they can locate the chest in order to "legitimately" find it quicker in the game.  I suppose if every game location is a key that resolves (client-side) to a gold key (or not) then it could work (almost) in the sense that the cheater puts in barely less work than the real player.  I was really hoping that my queries for clarity would result in someone better than me providing an answer tbh.

Comment: ...and ultimately, through talking with you, I've come to think you're right: the answer is in the design itself. No amount of keys are a "magic bullet" in this case.